# Design of the frontpage is broken at 110% zoom

Tags: bug, design, homepage

The frontpage looks like the following screenshot for me as I have a zoom level of 110% set:

[image]

It looks perfectly fine if I set the zoom to 100%, but then the text is a bit too small for me. I'm using the latest Chrome on Windows 7.

Comment: ["Doctor, it hurts when I do this!"](https://i.chzbgr.com/maxW500/3603757056/hF48AD100/)

Comment: @Emracool - But what if we are using that zoom level by default?

Comment: @hims056 Yeah, that's fair. It's a legitimate bug, but that's an interim solution. I'm just being sarcastic :P

Comment: @Emracool On a monitor with a bit higher pixel density it can be necessary to use the zoom level to be able to comfortably read the text.

Comment: @Mad Ahh, that makes sense. Apologies!

Comment: Too much [design related bugs](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug+design) going to be reported in MSE.